# Join two simple SQL queries

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables, `ORDER` and `CART`.

The following query returns all `OrderId`'s associated with the customer email

```
SELECT [OrderId], [Email]
FROM [ORDER]
WHERE [Email] = 'customer1@email.com'
```

Now I manually copy pasting `OrderId` to following quarries to return all `CartId`'s associate with those `OrderId`'s

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [CartId], [OrderId], [Name]
FROM [CART]
WHERE [OrderId] = 123
   OR [OrderId] = 456
   OR [OrderId] = 789
```

How can I join this two SQL queries to ease my work? I'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the following join:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1000 c.CartId, c.OrderId, c.Name
FROM [CART] c
INNER JOIN [ORDER] o
    ON o.OrderId = c.OrderId
WHERE o.Email = 'customer1@email.com';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use join as follows

```
SELECT [cartid],
       C.[orderid],
       [name],
       [email]
FROM   [cart] C
       JOIN [order] O
         ON O.[orderid] = C.[orderid]
WHERE  o.[email] = 'customer1@email.com'
```

Comment: `orderid` is ambigious here.